# What does the comparison mean and why isn't it showing true nor false?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying the following and as expected, I get two columns with the values.

```
declare @aa varchar(10) = 'bb'
declare @bb varchar(10) = 'aa'
select @aa, @bb
```

Then I tried the following and I can't explain the result. I see nothing, except the command executed successfully.

```
declare @aa varchar(10) = 'bb'
declare @bb varchar(10) = 'aa'
select @aa = @bb
```

What have I done here? I was expecting a true/false or one/zero or an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do comparison in a query:

```
select
    case 
        when @aa = @bb then 'MATCH'
        else 'NOT MATCH'
    end
```

With what you were doing:

```
select @aa, @bb
```

The above selects both values stored in the variables as separate "columns".

```
select @aa = @bb
```

The above sets the variable `@aa` equal to the value of `@bb`.

Comment: Following up on the question - what if I want to compare the string as but with respect to equality but **inequality**? Let's say that I wish to compare if the first one is alphabetically speaking before the second. Is it OK to use inequality signs in the *when*-condition or is that going to create problems later on?

Answer (score 4):

`select @aa = @bb` is assignment like `SET @aa = @bb`

Compare using [IIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx) `SELECT IIF(@aa = @bb, 'Same', 'Different')`

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/1918/0)**

Inequality `SELECT IIF(@aa <> @bb, 'Different', 'Same')`

In General `SELECT IIF((condition), 1, 0)` where 1 is true, 0 is false.

Comment: I'm getting syntax error at the equality sign. Is it perhaps valid command (IFF, that is) for other DBs than mine? I'm using Sql Server 14. I assumed that such a basic operation surely should have the same syntax in all versions but *assuming* is partly build on *ass*, which is what I might have been...

Comment: @KonradViltersten See my updated answer, I attach live demo.

Answer (score 1):

You are not comparing the variables rather you are assigning the variables. = operator will assign the values.

You can try like this:

```
declare @aa varchar(10) = 'bb'
declare @bb varchar(10) = 'aa'
if(@aa = @bb)
    print  'Match'
else
    print  'Not Match'
```

or more compact use the `IIF`

```
SELECT IIF(@aa = @bb, 'Match', 'Not Match')
```